# How to fix SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a Python program wherein if I type What is your name - it should display my name. I went like this first:

```
>>> What is your name = 'Marif'
```

but it gave syntax error. Then I tried:

```
>>> 'what is your name' = 'Marif'
```

and it gave:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal.
```

Comment: Are you trying to do e.g. `input('what is your name')`? As the error tells you, assigning a value to a string literal makes no sense; it already *is* a value. Maybe see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html.

Comment: I just need to know how to get the result (my name) when I print What is your name

Comment: Then I'd really recommend reading a tutorial. You could also read up on the function I mentioned above, that's documented too.

Answer (score -1):

You want to compare an input somebody gave via keyboard with a text, and you want the program to act on that input (e.g. showing your name if it was the question mentioned).

First of all, you need to realize what a variable is. You need to declare a variable and put the input from the console into it. Then you want to compare this input, and act accordingly. Something like:

```
inputFromConsole = (input)
if (inputFromConsole = "What is your name?"):
    print("Marif")
```

That said, you should try one of the many python tutorials out in the web, as those beginner questions are regularly answered there.